# How can I delete an article listed on my Google Scholar page that was not written by me?

Tags: google-scholar

On top of my Google Scholar page an article appears that was not written by me (increases my citations quite a bit, but I feel it reflects badly on me). For whatever reason, the article doesn't appear on my underlying profile page, so I cannot delete it. Is there a way to delete it? I send emails to Google Scholar help but no answer. Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between your Google Scholar page and profile page?

Comment: when you go on the menu on top left of the page and click on "my profile" that is the underlying profile page I meant

Comment: Yes, but what's the other page then? The citation counts you see are based on the articles in your profile page, right?

Comment: the "regular" google scholar page. Perhaps there is some confusion because I had at some point two scholar pages, but not sure

Comment: That seems likely. I have no idea what the other "regular" page is, but if it exists perhaps someone else will answer.

Comment: Thanks, GoodDeeds, in any case.

Comment: Make sure to have only one single Google Scholar profile first. There should be only one version of a profile, not two different ones.